# regular-expressions for email validation

Tags: regex, validation, email-validation

i am making a password and email page and need to validate the email with a reg-ex.
my problem is the reg-ex i use will only validate to after the @ sign after that point all emails are valid,i need a full proof reg-ex that validates and makes sure its either ".com" or the English alternative (spell check wont accept) at the end can anyone help?

My code for anyone needing it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function checkForm(form)
    {
    if(form.email.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
      form.email.focus();
      return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if(!re.test(form.email.value)) {
      alert("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
      form.email.focus();
      return false;
    }

    if(form.pwd1.value != "" && form.pwd1.value == form.pwd2.value) {
      if(form.pwd1.value.length < 6) {
        alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      if(form.pwd1.value == form.email.value) {
        alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[0-9]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[a-z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
      re = /[A-Z]/;
      if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
      form.pwd1.focus();
      return false;
    }

    alert("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
    return true;
  }

   </script>

   <form ... onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
   <p>email: <input type="email" name="email"></p>
   <p>Password: <input type="password" name="pwd1"></p>
   <p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pwd2"></p>
   <p><input type="submit"></p>
   </form>
```

Comment: [This relevant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) comes from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496). It's listed under "Common Tasks"

Answer (score 1):

The [real regex to properly validate email addresses according to the spec is massive,](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt) and probably not what you want to actually do. Remember that .NET, .COM, .TRAVEL, .CA, and [many many more](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) are valid top-level domains and can have email sent to and from them.

Instead, consider doing very simple regex validation (check for an @ sign) and send a verification email to confirm that the email address is valid. Rely on the user to input their madness-inducing emails correctly.

See [this relevant Programmers discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation).